# Em Orientação a Objetos, uma herança viola o encapsulamento?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, herança, encapsulamento

Segundo o livro *Padrões de Projeto* escrito por *Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson e John Vlissides*, realizam uma afirmação:

**"...a herança viola o encapsulamento."**

Segue abaixo o parágrafo que contém esta afirmação:

> "*... a herança de classe tem também algumas desvantagens. Em primeiro lugar, você não pode mudar as implementações herdadas das classes ancestrais em tempo de execução, porque a herança é definida em tempo de compilação. Em segundo lugar, e geralmente isso é o pior, as classes ancestrais frequentemente definem pelo menos parte da representação física das suas subclasses. Porque a herança expõe para uma subclasse os detalhes de implementação dos seus ancestrais, frequentemente é dito que **"a herança viola o encapsulamento"** [Sny86]. A implementação de uma subclasse, dessa forma, torna-se tão amarrada à implementação da sua classe-mãe que qualquer mudança na implementação desta forçará uma mudança naquela."*

Eu não consegui visualizar na prática essa afirmação. Como que a herança viola o encapsulamento? Para elucidar melhor o entendimento, um exemplo que justifique essa afirmação é bem-vinda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso significa que o acoplamento é forte e qualquer alteração de código na classe base, afeta as subclasses.

Por isso, não se recomenda fazer a herança para reaproveitamento de código. Porque se uma função precisar ser alterada na classe original, afetará todas as filhas e a solução fácil seria violar o encapsulamento (tornando protegido ou público algo que faria mais sentido como privado).

Em muitos casos hoje, se recomenda a composição no lugar da herança para estruturar um código. O objetivo é delegar partes menores para uma classe que é parte da classe maior.

Por exemplo, criando a classe Reserva e a classe Compra para fazerem parte da classe Transação. Nesse caso, deixa todas as funções bem separadas e com comportamentos bem definidos.

Answer (score 5):

Temos que ver essa discussão do ponto de vista do que é **encapsulamento**:

> Um mecanismo de restrição de acesso aos elementos da classe

O encapsulamento permite que você crie uma implementação isolada, portanto você pode testar isoladamente e garantir que mudanças na implementação (sem mudar a interface) tem impacto **zero** no restante do sistema.

O oposto disso, apenas para dar um contraste, é você mudar uma linha de código e ter que testar metade do sistema por causa de um código ruim extremamente acoplado.

Com isso em mente, a herança viola o encapsulamento no sentido de que a mudança em uma superclasse tem o potencial de afetar todas as subclasses.

Pense no caso onde uma superclasse é usada em vários projetos e agora todos eles precisarão ser atualizados e testados novamente.

Em geral, isso não ocorre se uma superclasse tem membros `private` (privados). Por outro lado, quando falamos em membros que podem ser acessados por subclasses (`protected`, por exemplo) temos que entender que, do ponto de vista da subclasse, `protected` e `public` são a mesma coisa, então é como se não existisse encapsulamento algum.

Finalmente, usar herança em contextos errados (não que seja fácil saber) leva você rapidamente de:

> Olha que legal essa minha "super classe" que meus 10 colegas podem simplesmente estender e ter quase tudo implementado "de graça".

Para, depois de algum tempo:

> Putz! Tenho que mudar essa porcaria de classe abstrata de novo, pedir para meus 10 colegas atualizarem as implementações deles, testar tudo novamente e exigir que todos os módulos do sistema sejam atualizados ao mesmo tempo em produção!

Comment: +1, só uma dúvida, no último parágrafo, você quis dizer "privado" ali como tradução de `private` certo?

Comment: @DiegoF isso mesmo

Answer (score 4):

A herança, tal qual se ensinava em OO nos anos 90 (na época em que diziam que OO ia acabar com a fome no mundo), tem surpreendentemente poucos usos legítimos. Eu não usaria a expressão "viola o encapsulamento", eu diria antes que a herança "engessa" as subclasses. Linguagens "anos 90" tipo Delphi, que só tinham herança como meio de reutilização de código, tinham profundas hierarquias de classe no seu framework (vinha até um chart na caixinha do produto, tamanho A3, pra colar na parede), e quebrava tudo a cada versão nova.

Fica ainda mais canhestro quando se permite herança múltipla. Aquela coisa de "Quadrado é subclasse de Retângulo mas também é subclasse de PolígonoRegular"... aí "Círculo" deveria ser subclasse de "PolígonoRegular" ou não?? Ao menos descobriram ainda nos anos 90 que herança múltipla não era uma boa idéia, e o único uso realmente legítimo era a aderência a interfaces, ou seja, herança simples de uma classe concreta e herança múltipla de classes puramente abstratas (o Java é assim desde sempre).

Às vezes esse engessamento é perfeitamente adequado. Na totalidade dos frameworks visuais que conheço, cada controle da tela é descendente de uma classe View (UIView no iOS, View no Android, etc.) Nesse caso a herança é adequada porque as views derivadas têm de adequar-se rigidamente aos protocolos e ao funcionamento da View de base; e a View de base implementa a totalidade da funcionalidade básica (é ela, e não a derivada, que vai "conversar" com o driver de vídeo, etc.) Se a View mudar seu modus operandi, é legítimo e desejável "quebrar" todas as derivadas de View, de preferência em tempo de compilação, para que sejam readaptadas.

Mas na maioria dos casos essa herança hierárquica é uma forma ruim de reutilizar código. Mesmo a herança de interfaces é obsoleta, os "protocolos" do Objective-C/Swift ou "duck typing" de linguagens interpretadas, são muito melhores. Essas linguagens também permitem adicionar métodos a uma classe sem precisar definir uma subclasse ("composição"). Esses recursos permitem frameworks com hierarquias bem "rasas". como é o caso do UIKit da Apple: https://finalizedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/uikit_classes.jpg

Em resumo, o uso excessivo de herança era uma conseqüência dos poucos recursos das linguagens disponíveis, da "novidade" das técnicas de OO, e do mau entendimento do OO "de verdade" tal qual implementado em Smalltalk.

Comment: Resposta muito esclarecedora. Praticamente uma aula de história! :)

Answer (score 3):

Em alguns momentos você pode acabar caindo em situações em que a implementação interna da classe mãe vai gerar comportamentos estranhos quando você sobrescrever algum método dela.

Ex: Caso que gera Stackoverflow

```
public class InheritanceOverflow {

  public static class Parent {

    public void foo() {
      bar();
    }

    public void bar() {}
  }

  public static class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void bar() {
      // Não há como saber nesse ponto que o método foo chama o método bar
      // isso irá gerar uma recursão infinita
      foo();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Child().bar();
  }
}
```

Basicamente esse exemplo quebra o encapsulamento pois você terá que saber qual a implementação interna da classe mãe pra poder resolver esse problema.