# Não consegui entender muito bem o encapsulamento na POO

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, encapsulamento

Fiz um curso de lógica de programação e agora estou fazendo de lógica OO, mas chegou na parte de encapsulamento e estou com um pouquinho de dificuldade de entender. O que seria e como é usado?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Minha experiência é que a maioria dos cursos se dizem sobre orientação a objeto porque todo mundo quer aprender isso. E todo mundo quer aprender porque dizem que ele cura até câncer. O que está longe da verdade. É uma pena porque as pessoas ficam procurando o cálice sagrado da OOP e sequer aprendem outras formas, não aprendem quando usar OO ou não, e pior, geralmente não aprendem o querido paradigma direito.

OOP não foi criada para facilitar o aprendizado, pelo contrário é bem mais difícil aprender e fazer código orientado a objeto, e só quem é ingênuo e não aprende direito é que acha que é fácil, o que obviamente faz tudo errado e não se beneficia do que o paradigma promete, mas [ela não tem condições de avaliar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect), ela apenas confia que está tendo alguma vantagem.

A maioria dos códigos ditos OOP que vemos por aí não são OOP ou abusam de recursos que não são necessários.

Não passe para OOP sem entender bem o [imperativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101) muito, mas muito bem mesmo. Se ainda não entende cada detalhe do código não vá para conceitos mais avançados e não tão necessários assim. Quase todo mundo ignora esta dica, é uma pena porque os que não ignoraram hoje são desenvolvedores bons e respondem aqui enquanto os que ignoram continuam batendo cabeça em cada código que tentam fazer.

Grosso modo, até porque tem várias definições, e as pessoas não conseguem concordar o que seja de fato.

O encapsulamento é juntar todos detalhes sobre o objeto, além disso costuma-se expor apenas o que se estabelece como uma [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101), uma garantia, uma contrato que jamais será mudado, o que aí já entra a abstração. Tudo que está encapsulado pode ser mudado sem problemas, desde que continue cumprindo tudo o que a classe se propõe. Então tanto estado como comportamento privado é criado para atender os requisitos da classe sem se comprometer com um jeito especifico de fazer.

Então boa parte do que se fala de encapsulamento se confunde com abstração, apesar de serem coisas diferentes. Inclusive um dos mecanismos usados para isso é *information hiding* que não é bem uma técnica tão geral, é algo mais específico e por isso não é um [pilar de orientação a objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101).

O encapsulamento facilita a manutenção porque cria uma caixa fechada onde o consumidor não precisa saber os detalhes e tem ali tudo o que precisa, como é um objeto mesmo. Você não precisa saber o que tem dentro, não precisa recorrer a outras coisas para lidar com aquilo, o que precisa está ali no objeto de alguma forma. Não expondo estas partes evita o uso indevido ou inadequado, aumentando a legibilidade do código.

É como um carro, você precisa saber dirigi-lo, não como ele funciona, inclusive cada carro pode funcionar muito diferente e você sabe como usar todos eles, as diferenças estão encapsuladas e abstraídas. Você conhece o carro, não precisa saber de rodas, de motor, de elétrica, há uma coesão do que é um carro.

[image: Como um carro é composto]

Tem várias perguntas obre o assunto, aconselho ler todas e pesquisar mais:

- [Significado da terminologia "Orientado a objeto"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101)
- [Quais são os pilares da programação orientada à objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101)
- [Por que esconder a implementação de uma classe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236069/101)
- [O que acontece na vida real em um ambiente de desenvolvedores se o programador não encapsular um atributo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204355/101)
- [É correto afirmar que o encapsulamento visa a coesão? Por que?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96656/101)
- [Qual a relação entre encapsulamento e polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214767/101)
- [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101)
- [Em Orientação a Objetos, uma herança viola o encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119481/101)
- [Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Valeu, sou iniciante, vou seguir a sua dica.

Comment: Então encapsular seria entregar somente o necessário para o usuário sem expor as funcionalidades internas do software.

Comment: Isso. No caso o usuário é o programador. Porque estamos falando de código, o usuário final não vê seu código, apenas programadores veem. E o programador pode ser você daqui 6 meses ou outro da equipe ou quem venha mexer neste código ou ainda um cliente de uma biblioteca sua. Estamos falando só sobre o desenvolvimento em si, não do produto final.