# É possível passar um vetor por parâmetro sem instanciá-lo?

Tags: java, arraylist

Eu queria passar um `vetor` (ou um `ArrayList`) por parâmetro sem instanciá-lo, mas estou bem perdido quanto a isso, pois normalmente eu instancio uma lista objeto e vou adicionando os dados nesta lista, porém como quero simplesmente passar um único elemento para esta lista, me surgiu a ideia de que seria possível passar por parâmetro esta lista de objeto sem instanciá-la.

Construtor da minha classe:

```
public User(String email, String password, List<Role> roles) {
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.roles = roles;
}
```

Tentei instanciar meu objeto `User` da seguinte maneira:

```
User user = new User(
    email, 
    passwords, 
    new ArrayList<Role>(roleRepository.findByRole("USER"))
);
```

Sem obter sucesso, tentei criando outro construtor:

```
 public User(String email, String password, Role[] roles) {
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    AddNewRole(null, roles);
    this.recordLogSeparated = false;
}
```

E um método para passar o valor à minha lista dentro da minha entidade.

```
private void AddNewRole(Role role, Role [] roles ) {
    if (this.roles.isEmpty() )
        this.roles = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i =0; i< roles.length; i++) {
        this.roles.add(roles[i]);
    }
}
```

Dai, agora tentei instanciar meu objeto `User` da seguinte maneira

```
User user = new User(
    email, 
    passwords, 
    [roleRepository.findByRole("USER"))]
);
```

Existe alguma alternativa para que não seja necessário executar as alternativas abaixo?

```
List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
roles.add(roleRepositoryJPA.findByRole("USER"));
```

ou

```
Role roles [] = {roleRepositoryJPA.findByRole("USER")};
```

Comment: Parece que está perguntando se dá pra fazer um bife sem matar o boi. Pode ser que não seja isto, mas não está muito claro o quer. É possível você não matar o boi, pode comprar no supermercado, mas alguém matou. Pode ser que não precise do bife, pode querer só uma proteína e poderia ser soja, mas como vamos saber?

Comment: Quando você vai escrever uma lista de compras e vai anotar os items em um papel você primeiro precisa ter o papel. E se é uma lista de um único item por que criar uma lista?

Comment: @ViniciusFernandes, meu objeto pode possuir uma lista, de permissões, mas para este cenário, inicialmente terá uma única permissão

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem sua pergunta, você quer passar direto uma lista de objetos, acredito que o código abaixo funcione:

```
User user = new User(
email, 
passwords, 
Arrays.asList(roleRepository.findByRole("USER"))
);
```

Comment: Obrigado meu caro, era exatamente isso que estava procurando...

Answer (score 7):

Se você tem um construtor que recebe uma lista, não tem como chamá-lo sem ter uma lista (a menos que você passe `null`, claro, mas creio que não é esse o propósito).

Então a resposta para "*É possível passar um vetor (ou lista) por parâmetro sem instanciá-lo?*" é **não**. Aliás, se precisar passar **qualquer** objeto como parâmetro (assumindo que não vai passar `null`), você precisará, em algum momento, instanciá-lo. Não tem como fugir disso.

A resposta que você aceitou usa [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)), e esse método [também instancia uma lista](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l3799). Só porque você não instanciou a lista diretamente, não quer dizer que ela não está sendo instanciada em outro lugar.

Na verdade o máximo que você conseguiu com `Arrays.asList` foi economizar uma ou duas linhas de código (pois não precisou criar a lista antes). Mas você ainda está instanciando uma lista.

Mas tudo bem, talvez o que você quis dizer é que só queria economizar essas linhas mesmo (sem ter que criar a lista diretamente), e tenha se expressado mal ao dizer "sem instanciá-lo", mas é bom deixar claro que sim, a lista está sendo instanciada (*e desculpe estar sendo tão repetitivo, mas achei importante frisar isso...*)

---

Tem outro detalhe: `Arrays.asList` retorna uma lista "mais ou menos" imutável. Então se você tentar adicionar elementos na lista, vai dar erro. Por exemplo, se a classe `User` tiver um método para adicionar outra `Role`:

```
public class User {

    public User(String email, String password, List<Role> roles) {
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public void addRole(Role role) {
        this.roles.add(role);
    }
}

...

User user = new User(email, password, Arrays.asList(role1));
user.addRole(role2); // erro!
```

Este código lança um `UnsupportedOperationException`, pois a lista retornada por `Arrays.asList` não permite que novos elementos sejam adicionados (o mesmo erro ocorre se tentar remover elementos da lista). Mas como eu disse, a lista retornada por `Arrays.asList` é "mais ou menos" imutável, já que ela permite que se mude um elemento já existente. Por exemplo:

```
public class User {
...
    public void mudaRole(Role role, int posicao) {
        this.roles.set(posicao, role);
    }
}

...

User user = new User(email, password, Arrays.asList(role1));
user.mudaRole(role2, 0); // muda a Role da posição 0 da lista
```

Nesse caso o código funciona, pois a lista retornada por `Arrays.asList` permite que se mude o elemento em uma posição já existente.

Dependendo de como você vai manipular a lista de *roles*, isso pode ou não fazer diferença. Por isso é importante saber a implicação de cada método que você usa, e não usá-lo simplesmente para "economizar uma linha de código". [Um código menor não é necessariamente "melhor"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052).

---

#### Alternativa: *varargs*

Uma alternativa para "economizar linhas" é usar [*varargs*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html):

```
public User(String email, String password, Role... roles) {
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.roles = Arrays.asList(roles);
}

...
// pode passar uma Role
User user = new User(email, password, role1);

// ou pode passar várias de uma vez
User user = new User(email, password, role1, role2, role3);
```

A sintaxe `Role... roles` indica que você pode passar uma ou mais roles (ou nenhuma, e nesse caso a lista será vazia).

Internamente, [a JVM "converte" esses parâmetros para um array de `Role`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21746663), por isso ainda é necessário convertê-lo para uma lista. Eu usei `Arrays.asList`, mas você poderia criar de outro jeito se quisesse. Por exemplo:

```
this.roles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(roles));
```

Esse caso é um pouco diferente: eu crio uma lista com todos os roles (usando `Arrays.asList`), e crio um `ArrayList` contendo os elementos desta lista. A diferença aqui é que esta lista não é "meio imutável" como ocorre se eu só chamar `Arrays.asList` (com o `ArrayList` eu posso adicionar e remover elementos).

Além disso, com *varargs* você [esconde a implementação interna da classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240186/112052): tanto faz se as *roles* estão em uma lista, um array ou qualquer outra estrutura interna, isso é detalhe de implementação da classe `User`; quem criar o usuário só precisa passar as roles que ele tem, sem precisar saber se dentro da classe ela vai criar uma lista ou não (e se um dia essa implementação interna mudar, as outras classes não precisam saber, pois o construtor continuará recebendo as roles do mesmo jeito).

Mas claro, se as roles ficarem em uma lista, então você ainda continuará instanciando uma lista (quem cria o `User` não precisa, é só passar as roles para o construtor, mas dentro da classe `User` tem uma instância sendo criada). Acho que já falei que não dá para escapar disso, né?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @hkotsubo, muito bem explicado.