# Encapsulamento private em herança

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento, private

A classe `SuperSuper` possui um atributo do tipo *private* e inteiro definidos. Qualquer especialização da classe `SuperSuper` poderá redefinir o encapsulamento para `public` e o seu dado é automaticamente convertido?

```
public class SuperSuper{
 public int a;
 private int b;
```

---

```
public class Super extends SuperSuper{

}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro atributo é algo que te ensinaram errado: [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

O que você está chamando de encapsulamento na verdade é *information hiding*, comece estudando mais o assunto em [Não consegui entender muito bem o encapsulamento na POO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240186/101).

Você está definindo a visibilidade do campo.

`Super` não vê o campo `b`, portanto ele não pode fazer **nada** com ele. Se fosse um `protected` ele veria, mas ainda não poderia mudar a visibilidade. No máximo poderia ter outro campo que transferiria de um para outro em um processo e esse novo campo em `Super` poderia ter outra visibilidade. Mas faria mais sentido apenas ter um método que acesse o campo protegido.

Eu costumo criticar as pessoas que usam `private` para tudo quando em algumas vezes não é necessário (é bom deixar claro que por deficiência da linguagem Java tende a precisar muito mais de *getters/setters*), mas esse não parece um caso que deva fazer ele ter uma visibilidade diferente. Claro, não posso afirmar categoricamente porque o exemplo é artificial, e em exemplos artificias não dá para aprender com fazer o correto, ou seja, não está aprendendo de verdade o que fazer.

Não tem conversão alguma a fazer e nada é feito automaticamente.

Se você muda o contrato na especialização deixando ele mais frouxo então não deve fazer herança aí: [Princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101).

Orientação a objeto é bem mais complicado que parece, não é só decorar mecanismos simples.

Comment: Só uma ressalva. Sobre os campos privados, entendo que você esteja falando que às vezes não faz mal um campo ser público. Para certas situações pode fazer sentido, embora a questão da extensibilidade sugira cautela com isso. Minha preocupação é com esse conselho parecer querer dizer que campos privados são má implementação quando na verdade são ótimos: dão o mínimo de visibilidade possível para um campo, o que é prudente, e não dão brecha para violação de encapsulamento (pois um campo protected, por exemplo, é um detalhe de implementação que via de regra não deve ser exposto para subclasses).