# Como eu posso atribuir valor há uma variável em uma classe no C#?

Tags: c#, classes, encapsulamento

Não estou conseguindo definir um valor para as variáveis dentro de uma classe.

Classe:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Encapsulamento_e_Modificadores_de_Acesso
{
    class Conta
    {
        private string Titular { get; set; }
        private double Saldo { get; set; }
        private int Numero { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Form1:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Encapsulamento_e_Modificadores_de_Acesso
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Conta c = new Conta();

            c.Titular = "Rodrigo";
            c.Numero = 1;
            c.Saldo = 100.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Mesmo utilizando o encapsulamento, ainda da o erro:

> CS0122 'Conta.Titular' é inacessível devido ao seu nível de proteção

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está descrito pelo compilador.

Se você quer acessar uma propriedade (não tem uma variável ali, veja mais nos *links* abaixo) publicamente precisa declarar ela como `public` e não como `private` que só permite acessá-la privativamente, ou seja, só dentro da própria classe. O que está fazendo não é encapsulamento.

Só para não dar a ideia que é só isso, o código tem outros problemas que permitirão compilar e executar, mas não né assim que se faz. Mas não é o foco da pergunta então é só um alerta que precisa ver outras coisas para não aprender errado. Procure material que ensine corretamente.

Para ver mais sobre o assunto:

- [Como funcionam as propriedades no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/101)
- [Propriedade Vs variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101)
- [Pra que usar de private?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165476/101)
- [Quão protegido está meu código, com variáveis privadas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189162/101)
- [Campo público X propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324099/101)
- [O que acontece na vida real em um ambiente de desenvolvedores se o programador não encapsular um atributo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204355/101)
- [Encapsulamento private em herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/502677/101)
- [Encapsulamento private em herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/502677/101)
- [É correto afirmar que o encapsulamento visa a coesão? Por que?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96656/101)
- [Não consegui entender muito bem o encapsulamento na POO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240186/101)
- [Métodos Getters e Setters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101)
- [Qual a relação entre encapsulamento e polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214767/101)
- [Quais são os pilares da programação orientada à objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101)
- [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101)

Aí já tem um material para estudar.

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada meu caro, muito obrigado!